# Does "Pact Initiate" grant the pact boon, too?

Tags: dnd-4e, multi-classing, warlock

As part of this Multiclass feat it tells me to:

> Choose a warlock pact. You gain the pact's at-will power as an encounter power, and you can pursue the warlock paragon path based on that pact.

Now according to the warlock features:

> Pact boon: Each pact includes a pact boon...

Now I understand that pact boon activates mainly when you have a warlock curse on an enemy, but nonetheless do you still have a pact boon because of this multiclassing feat?

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

> Choose a warlock pact. You gain the pact's at-will power as an encounter power...

So you *choose* the pact, but you only *gain* the at-will power.

The Warlock (Binder) class has 5 class features:

1. **Eldricht Blast**, which grants the homonymous power
2. **Eldricht Pact**, which lets you choose a pact and grants two things:

   1. An At-Will spell
   2. A Pact Boon
3. **Prime Shot**: +1 to hit enemies that are closer to you than to any of your allies (or at equal distance).
4. **Shadow Walk**, which grants concealment if you move at least 3 squares.
5. **Warlock's Curse**, the striker signature.

**Pact Initiate** gives you only the ability 2.1 (not the 2.2 which interacts with 5). As a plus, you are considered to have that pact for prerequisites' issues.

Comment: As I read the Eldritch Pact hybrid (PHB3) it clearly states: "This class feature functions as the warlock class feature, except you don't gain the at-will or the Pact Boon granted by it." It clearly says that you don't gain the pact boon there but not in the Pact Initiate.

Comment: Pact Initiate, instead, states you gain the pact's at-will spell, but does not mention the pact boon.